# Найти node в HTMLDocument(HtmlAgilityPack) по js innerHTML

Tags: javascript, c#, htmlagilitypack, cefsharp

Я использую CefSharp и js чтобы получить innerHTML элемента, на который нажали, и затем я хочу найти node в HtmlDocument, но не получается.
Ниже просто код вставленного в страницу js-a и парсится страница в HtmlDocument

```
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    CefSharp.PostMessage(e.target.parentElement.innerHTML);
    }, false);
");
browser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml => { html.LoadHtml(taskHtml.Result); });
```

innerHTML может возвращать изображения

```
"<img data-src=\"//img0.happywear.ru/230x350/cache/goods/H/F/HF130EK_т.синий_front.jpg\" title=\"Полотенце махровое 70x130 см Happy Fox Home\" alt=\"Полотенце махровое 70x130 см Happy Fox Home\" class=\"content_product_catalog_list_item_img lazy loaded\" src=\"//img0.happywear.ru/230x350/cache/goods/H/F/HF130EK_т.синий_front.jpg\" data-was-processed=\"true\">
```

или что-то подобное когда человек кликает на текст

```
"<p class=\"price-block_title\">опт</p> <p class=\"price-block_wholesale\">139&nbsp;₽</p>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как найти ноду по innerHTML. Или же как получить нажатый элемент(в браузере через библиотеку CefSharp) таким образом, чтобы потом с ним работать через библиотеку HtmlAgilityPack.
Если же есть библиотеки, позволяющие получить нажатый элемент со страницы и затем работать с ним(переходить к родителям его или чайлдом и все такое(например, находить элементы с похожим классом), то, пожалуйста, напишите.

Comment: Так что за ноду найти то надо? И в вашем вопросе нет ни одного знака вопроса. Приведите пример запроса для `QuerySelector`, как бы вы сделали в JS. Покажите метод полностью, из которого вы выдернули код с `browser`.

Comment: Ноду надо найти элемента, на который нажал пользователь, по возвращенному innerHTML. Его примеры есть в описании.

Comment: Суть задачи вообще в том, чтобы получить нажатый элемент на сайте и работать потом с ним в рамках HTMLAgilityPack.

Comment: Если эта нода к вам возвращается, зачем ее искать, если она уже у вас есть?

Comment: Позвращается innerHTML(просто строка), по которому надо найти ноду в htmlDocument, ну или раз уж на то пошло превратить его в ноду(этого я тоже не знаю). Нужно будет переходить по родителям и чайлдам, а со строкой нужно вручную это все делать.

Comment: Для начала попробуйте вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783590/12888024) - сформировать путь к ноде и отправлять из скрипта его, а не внутрянку этой ноды. Затем можно сформировать `XPath` запрос и через [`DocumentNode.SelectNodes`](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) можно найти нужную ноду. Либо если вам ближе JS, то вместо `SelectNodes` можно дополнительно установить NuGet пакет `Fizzler.Systems.HtmlAgilityPack` и использовать `DocumentNode.QuerySelector("...")`, который на вход принимает запрос, синтаксис которого идентичен JS `document.querySelector("...")`.

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Вы скинули как раз то, что нужно было. Ноду решил получать функцией getNode, написанной в ответе на вопрос, который вы скинули. Еще раз спасибо. Жаль, что не могу повысить вам репутацию за ваш комментарий(

Comment: Для того чтобы дать ответ, было недостаточно информации в вопросе, поэтому это был не ответ, а догадка. Но вы можете оформить ответ на свой вопрос самостоятельно, и затем его принять. Возможно, он станет полезным для других посетителей.

Comment: *Дополнительно:* Если покажете в ответе весь метод целиком, возможно еще помогу его в порядок привести, потому что у вас по-старому организована работа с асинхронными вызовами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря человеку под ником aepot был найден способ получения ноды, нажатого элемента, путем записывания "пути"(массив номеров child-ов) до него на js и затем прохождения по этому пути до нужного элемента.
Ниже код функции, которая выполняется при вызове события FrameLoadEnd у ChromiumWebBrowser из CefSharp.
Она инжектит скрипт, который возвращает путь до нужной ноды

```
public async void OnFrameLoadEnd(object sender, FrameLoadEndEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                //In the main frame we inject some javascript that's run on mouseUp
                //You can hook any javascript event you like.
                browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(@"
                    document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    e = e || window.event;
                    target = e.target || e.srcElement;
                    CefSharp.PostMessage(getPath(target));
                    }, false);
                    function getIndex (node) {
                      var parent=node.parentElement||node.parentNode, i=-1, child;
                      while (parent && (child=parent.childNodes[++i])) if (child==node) return i;
                      return -1;
                    }
                    function getPath (node) {
                      var parent, path=[], index=getIndex(node);
                      (parent=node.parentElement||node.parentNode) && (path=getPath(parent));
                      index > -1 && path.push(index);
                      return path;
                    }
                ");
                await browser.GetSourceAsync().ContinueWith(taskHtml => { html.LoadHtml(taskHtml.Result); });
            }
        }
```

Затем при получении сообщения от браузера(ивент JavascriptMessageReceived) с путем просто идем до ноды. clickedItem и есть нудная нода.

```
private void OnBrowserJavascriptMessageReceived(object sender, JavascriptMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            var windowSelection = (List<object>)e.Message;
            HtmlNode clickedItem = html.DocumentNode;
            for (int i = 0; i < windowSelection.Count; ++i)
                clickedItem = clickedItem.ChildNodes[(int)windowSelection[i]];
        }
```

Еще раз спасибо aepot, который нашел и скинул ссылку на вопрос(благодаря которому был найден способ решения задачи) в комментариях к моему вопросу. :)